# Which version of UUID does MySQL use?

Tags: mysql, node.js, uuid

I'm rewriting an old Node.js app that uses UUID. I decided to move the responsibility of generating UUID's to Node instead of MySQL's `UUID()` function.

The package I'm gonna use on Node is `uuid`, which has support for version 1, 4, and 5. For compatibility reason, I need to use the same version which is generated by MySQL's `UUID()`. Which one is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid):

> UUID() returns a value that conforms to UUID version 1 as described in RFC 4122.